# Script to compare 2 input paramters and show shared letter(s)

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script

I am writing a script that I want a user to enter two separate words, and the result to show which letter the two words share. For instance ./share Cat Rat - would return shared letters: "a" and "t". My thought was to read through $1 and $2 in a loop, but after that, I'm not really sure where to go. I am just starting to learn scripting and unix so any help is appreciated!

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "$1"|while read line
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux SE. You can verify some answers for your questions from [here](http://www.unix.com/unix-for-dummies-questions-and-answers/33481-matching-characters-between-strings.html).

Comment: @Ramesh appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a preferred language? This would be pretty easy in perl, but doable in bash/ksh

Comment: @glennjackman preferred in bash/sh, only because that is what I'm trying to familiarize myself with.

Answer (score 5):

If you can rely on Bash builtin regular expressions (namely the `=~` operator) and array variables, you can use something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
W1=( $( echo "$1" | sed "s/./\n&/g" | sort -u ) )
W2="$2"
set ${W1[*]}

while [[ ! -z "$1" ]]; do
    if [[ "$W2" =~ "$1" ]]; then
        printf "$1 "
    fi
    shift
done
printf "\n"
```

The first line creates an array that contains every single character contained in `$1`. Next, `$2` is saved and then the positional parameters are set to the values of `$W1` elements. Then every character (now positional parameter) is matched against the saved second word and if match is found, it is printed. Last, positional parameters are shifted so that the loop continues with the next character.

Concepts that you can see here: working with an array, capturing output of a command into a variable, changing positional arguments, loop and conditional statement.

If you want to do it simply, you might want to consider for example this one (actually it is a one-liner split for increased readability):

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "$1" \
    | sed "s/./\n&/g" | sort -u \
    | grep -F "$( printf "$2" | sed 's/./&\n/g' | sort -u )"
```

The `sed | sort -u` combos just split the words into one unique character per line forms. `grep -F` treats the parameter (here the split second word) as fixed strings that are to be matched in the input and thus it tries to match every single character in `$1` with every character in `$2`. In real situations you would probably remove the second `sort | uniq` combo, since "words" are usually rather short and any performance gain would be killed by spawning two additional processes. However, as `$2` gets bigger (hundreds or thousands of lines), you definitely want to do any optimization possible.

You can also replace the `sed` command with `fold -w 1` which does almost the same (it is shorter to type, but `sed`'s `s` command is the Swiss Army knife of text processing).

Comment: +1.  But why use `sort | uniq` when `sort -u` will suffice?  Also according to the docs, [`fold -w1` is better than `fold -1`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/fold-invocation.html) (unless you're playing [code-golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/17305/transpose-a-page-of-text/24501#24501) ;-))

Comment: @DigitalTrauma You're right, thanks. :) As for the `sort | uniq` combo, no special reason. I guess I wasn't sure it `-u` is POSIX ([it is](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sort.html)).

Answer (score 4):

following is a simple approach that iterates over the first string and checks if each character is present in the second string, if the character is present then it will print that on the console.

```
str1=$1;
i=0
while [ $i -ne ${#str1} ]
 do
 c=${str1:$i:1}
 if [[ $2 == *$c* ]]
  then
   echo $c
 fi
 ((i++))
done
```

Comment: +1 but a `for ((i=1; i=${#str}; i++))` loop is a little more compact

Answer (score 3):

If you like snazzy little one-liners, and are OK with using common tools from GNU coreutils, then you can do something like this:

```
comm -12 <( fold -w1 <<< "$1" | sort -u ) <( fold -w1 <<< "$2" | sort -u )
```

If you don't care about the case of the letters, you can switch `$1` and `$2` with `${1,,}` and `${2,,}` respectively.

As well as the [`comm`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/comm-invocation.html), [`fold`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/fold-invocation.html) and [`sort`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html) utilities, this uses `<( )` [command substiutions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) and `<<<` [here-strings](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings).

---

Alternatively if you want a pure bash answer (no coreutils) and want some more exposure to various bash features, here's another:

```
declare -A arr
for (( i=0; i<${#1}; i++ )); do
    (( arr[${1:i:1}] |= 1 ))
done
for (( i=0; i<${#2}; i++ )); do
    (( arr[${2:i:1}] |= 2 ))
done
for i in ${!arr[@]}; do
    if (( ${arr[$i]} == 3 )); then
        echo $i
    fi
done
```

This uses a bash [associative array](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arrays), so requires version 4 or greater.

It also uses `(( ))` [arithmetic expansions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs) with bitwise arithmetic.

It works through the characters of the first string and uses each one as an index into the associative array.  The element corresponding to that index is ORed with 1 (or has its bit 0 set).

The same is done for the second string except that the element is ORed with 2 (or has its bit 1 set).

Then we walk through the array looking for elements that have bits 0 AND 1 set (i.e. equal to 3) and output the index (which is a common letter).